# SQL date query show non existing days

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I'm facing the following problem:

I need to query a Postgres database for the total downloads of every day since 2008,like

`date    | downloads
1-1-2008 | 20
3-1-2008 | 10`

the real problem is that i don't every an entry for every day but i need the also get the days when the downloads were zero.

The solution that is running now is to have another table with every date from 1-1-2008 to 1-1-2018.

And right joining into it on every date range oriented query....

is that the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `right join` to a [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) table

```
select s.d
from
    downloads d
    right join
    (
        select d::date
        from
        generate_series('2008-01-01', current_date, interval '1 day') s(d)
    ) s on s.d = d.d
```

Comment: Ok the solution seems more clean not having to have a satic table all the time, tho isn't it the same or worst performance wise? Since your are still right joining the "tables" and on this solution data is being generated for every request?

Comment: @Eduardo My guess it that it is cheaper to generate the data than to ask for it from the file system. It is also much more flexible as it applies not only to consecutive days but also to any imaginable interval.